# Oracle: Get every half hour between two times

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I've got some data with two times defining a time range.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TIME_TABLE
(
    MY_PK     NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL ENABLE,
    FROM_TIME DATE        NOT NULL ENABLE,
    TO_TIME   DATE        NOT NULL ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO MY_TIME_TABLE(MY_PK,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME)
VALUES(1,TO_DATE('2014-01-01 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

INSERT INTO MY_TIME_TABLE(MY_PK,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME)
VALUES(2,TO_DATE('2014-01-02 14:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('2014-01-02 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

INSERT INTO MY_TIME_TABLEMY_PK,(FROM_TIME,TO_TIME)
VALUES(3,TO_DATE('2014-01-03 00:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('2014-01-03 03:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

What I would like to do is create a query that would return all of the half hour blocks in between each of the two times. So it would return something like the following:

```
1, 2014-01-01 09:00:00
1, 2014-01-01 09:30:00
1, 2014-01-01 10:00:00
1, 2014-01-01 10:30:00
1, 2014-01-01 11:00:00
1, 2014-01-01 11:30:00
1, 2014-01-01 12:00:00
1, 2014-01-01 12:30:00
2, 2014-01-02 14:00:00
2, 2014-01-02 14:30:00
3, 2014-01-03 00:30:00
3, 2014-01-03 01:00:00
3, 2014-01-03 01:30:00
3, 2014-01-03 02:00:00
3, 2014-01-03 02:30:00
3, 2014-01-03 03:00:00
```

The data is guaranteed to start and end on the hour or half hour, so I don't have to worry about partial matches.

I normally try to show what I've done on my own to solve my problem, but in this case I don't even have the faintest clue where to start.

Comment: Look for `CTE` -- it's common way to generate series of data (i.e. dates).

Comment: You could find the number of periods between by subtracting the dates and div the minutes by 30, then use ((number table * periods in between) * 30) adding minutes back into the start time to create the timestamps.

Comment: Ah, I've not encountered CTE yet. I'll definitely look into it. bd33: That sounds like it could work, too. I'll be incorporating this into a larger query, though, and something tells me that could get complicated rather quickly. I won't know until I try it out, I guess.

Comment: What oracle version are you using?

Comment: I'm developing with 11g R2, but it has to work on 10g R2 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using a Hierarchical query or a CTE.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74704/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TIME_TABLE ( MY_PK, FROM_TIME, TO_TIME ) AS
SELECT  1, TO_DATE('2014-01-01 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT  2, TO_DATE('2014-01-02 14:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2014-01-02 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, TO_DATE('2014-01-03 00:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2014-01-03 03:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

**Hierarchical Query**:

```
SELECT MY_PK, FROM_TIME + (LEVEL-1) / 48
FROM MY_TIME_TABLE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TO_TIME - FROM_TIME) * 48
          AND PRIOR MY_PK = MY_PK
          AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74704/7/0)**:

```
| MY_PK |         FROM_TIME+(LEVEL-1)/48 |
|-------|--------------------------------|
|     1 | January, 01 2014 09:00:00+0000 |
|     1 | January, 01 2014 09:30:00+0000 |
|     1 | January, 01 2014 10:00:00+0000 |
|     1 | January, 01 2014 10:30:00+0000 |
|     1 | January, 01 2014 11:00:00+0000 |
|     1 | January, 01 2014 11:30:00+0000 |
|     1 | January, 01 2014 12:00:00+0000 |
|     1 | January, 01 2014 12:30:00+0000 |
|     2 | January, 02 2014 14:00:00+0000 |
|     2 | January, 02 2014 14:30:00+0000 |
|     3 | January, 03 2014 00:30:00+0000 |
|     3 | January, 03 2014 01:00:00+0000 |
|     3 | January, 03 2014 01:30:00+0000 |
|     3 | January, 03 2014 02:00:00+0000 |
|     3 | January, 03 2014 02:30:00+0000 |
|     3 | January, 03 2014 03:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this query! This will make it easy to incorporate it into the larger query that I'm building. I don't know how it compares to other solutions in terms of speed, but in this particular case at least simplicity is definitely the more important factor. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 11gR2 you can use [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55268) (aka recursive CTE or recursive with):

```
with r (my_pk, from_time, to_time) as (
  select my_pk, from_time, to_time
  from my_time_table
  union all
  select my_pk, from_time + interval '30' minute, to_time
  from r
  where from_time + interval '30' minute < to_time
)
select my_pk, to_char(from_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as from_time
from r
order by my_pk, from_time;

     MY_PK FROM_TIME         
---------- -------------------
         1 2014-01-01 09:00:00                       
         1 2014-01-01 09:30:00                       
         1 2014-01-01 10:00:00                       
         1 2014-01-01 10:30:00                       
         1 2014-01-01 11:00:00                       
         1 2014-01-01 11:30:00                       
         1 2014-01-01 12:00:00                       
         1 2014-01-01 12:30:00                       
         2 2014-01-02 14:00:00                       
         2 2014-01-02 14:30:00                       
         3 2014-01-03 00:30:00                       
         3 2014-01-03 01:00:00                       
         3 2014-01-03 01:30:00                       
         3 2014-01-03 02:00:00                       
         3 2014-01-03 02:30:00                       
         3 2014-01-03 03:00:00
```

The anchor clause gets the start time for each PK value, and the recursive parts keeps adding 30-minute intervals until the end time for that PK is reached. You can then use that CTE as a source table elsewhere in the query; here I'm just displaying the contents, clearly.

Depending on how you're going to use these ranges, you might find it useful to generate the end of each half-hour block as well, e.g. for use in a `between` clause in the main query:

```
with r (my_pk, from_time, to_time, max_time) as (
  select my_pk, from_time,
    from_time + interval '30' minute - interval '1' second, to_time
  from my_time_table
  union all
  select my_pk, from_time + interval '30' minute,
    to_time + interval '30' minute, max_time
  from r
  where from_time + interval '30' minute < max_time
)
select my_pk, to_char(from_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as from_time,
  to_char(to_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as to_time
from r
order by my_pk, from_time;

    MY_PK FROM_TIME           TO_TIME           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 2014-01-01 09:00:00 2014-01-01 09:29:59 
         1 2014-01-01 09:30:00 2014-01-01 09:59:59 
         1 2014-01-01 10:00:00 2014-01-01 10:29:59 
         1 2014-01-01 10:30:00 2014-01-01 10:59:59 
         1 2014-01-01 11:00:00 2014-01-01 11:29:59 
         1 2014-01-01 11:30:00 2014-01-01 11:59:59 
         1 2014-01-01 12:00:00 2014-01-01 12:29:59 
         1 2014-01-01 12:30:00 2014-01-01 12:59:59 
         2 2014-01-02 14:00:00 2014-01-02 14:29:59 
         2 2014-01-02 14:30:00 2014-01-02 14:59:59 
         3 2014-01-03 00:30:00 2014-01-03 00:59:59 
         3 2014-01-03 01:00:00 2014-01-03 01:29:59 
         3 2014-01-03 01:30:00 2014-01-03 01:59:59 
         3 2014-01-03 02:00:00 2014-01-03 02:29:59 
         3 2014-01-03 02:30:00 2014-01-03 02:59:59 
         3 2014-01-03 03:00:00 2014-01-03 03:29:59
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select my_pk, from_time + (half_hour_increment-1) * interval '30' minute new_time
from
(
    select my_pk, from_time, to_time, (to_time-from_time)*24*2 half_hours
    from my_time_table
) my_time_table
join
(
    select level half_hour_increment
    from
    (
        select max(to_time-from_time)*24*2 max_half_hours
        from my_time_table
    )
    connect by level <= max_half_hours
) row_generator
    on half_hours >= half_hour_increment
order by my_pk, half_hour_increment;
```